Where does the redirect from shortlink to permalink happen?
When requesting short urls they are redirected to their matching permalink, for instances :



shortlink
permalink




/?cat=category_id
/category_base/category_slug


/?p=post_or_page_id
/custom_structure/post_or_page_slug/


/?author=account_id
/author/account_slug



What's the part of the code handling this and is it customizable through hooks ?

That's handled by the redirect_canonical function, set up as a default template_redirect filter.
So it can be customized either by :

a template_redirect filter, with a priority value lower than 10, so it runs before the redirect_canonical function (which will eventually skip the next filters by making a redirect).
a redirect_canonical filter called by the function of the same name

